# How to see all values in the user’s theme configuration

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am writing plugin to add custom styles in TailwindCSS, but I am a bit confused with values of `theme()`. I don't know how to see all the theme values ​​to apply my base styles. How do I know where it is?

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addBase, addComponents, addUtilities, theme }) {
      addBase({
        'h1': {
          fontSize: theme('fontSize.2xl'), // need to see more fontSize and properties, where I can see it?
        },
        'h2': {
          fontSize: theme('fontSize.xl'),
        },
      })
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to it? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme